# Cocktail Party Problem using ICA

Tags: deep-learning, classification

If you already had a recording of two separate sound sources mixed, where one source was a person singing and the second source was a piano playing. Could ICA be used to separate the recording into 2 distinct sound sources?  If so, how would ICA be used to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done: [here’s a paper from 2015 indicating recent developments](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277139249_ICA-based_Single_Channel_Audio_Separation_New_Bases_and_Measures_of_Distance) and there’s [a handy dandy tutorial here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-ica-blind-source-separation-py) to get you started using scikit-learn’s ICA implementation. Enjoy!